# Override custom email template from admin

Tags: magento2, email, email-templates

I created a custom module that sends a custom email daily for report reasons. Everything is working fine

Now, I'd like to customize my custom template from admin in `Marketing->Email Templates`section.

How can I get that the module uses the customized template instead of the original one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer below example and let me know if you need further information.

https://www.aurigait.com/blog/how-to-create-custom-email-template-in-magento-2/

Comment: That was exactly what I needed, thank you @Nits!

Comment: Most welcome @DanieleRovatti